# Is ICollection<>.Add() thread safe?

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a collection as below?

```
public ICollection<MyClass> Property { get; private set; }
...
Property = new List<MyClass>();
```

I wish to add `MyClass` items into the `Property` after fetching each `MyClass` item from DB. Now each DB fetch is handled in separate background threads and they run simultaneously. So every return value from DB call will face `Property.Add()`. Now this may lead to race conditions as `Property.Add()` may be called multiple times at one instant.

So my question is does `List<>.Add()` or any other class implementing `ICollection<>.Add()` internally handle any race conditions or it needs to be explicitly handled? If so then how?

Comment: `ICollection<T>` is an interface. A concrete implementation of that interface may be thread-safe, or may not be, but it doesn't really make sense to talk of the thread-safety of the interface itself. The question should be whether `List<T>.Add()` is thread-safe.

Comment: The  collection classes in `System.Collections.Generic` do not provide any thread synchronization; user code must provide all synchronization when items are added or removed on multiple threads concurrently. If you need thread-safety look into the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: List isn't thread safe. This is mentioned in the `Thread Safety` secion in the [class's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). This section is present in the documentation of **all** .NET classes

Answer (score 9):

ICollection doesn't have any internals; it's an interface. The implementation might or might not be thread safe but the interface doesn't guarantee anything.

This might be useful to look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It seems like OP will know about `ICollection<T>` is an interface, this is why OP provided a sample code: `Property = new List<MyClass>();`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer perhaps, but the question (before it was edited) specifically asked how ICollection<T> handled race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle concurrency explicitly. This is why there's a namespace [called `System.Concurrent.Collections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).

If order doesn't matter, [you might need to take a look to `ConcurrentBag<T>`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) Otherwise, you'll need to provide your own implementation or derived class to provide thread-safety to any of out-of-the-box `ICollection<T>` implementations found in `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Your concrete type is `List<MyClass>`, so you should look at the thread-safety of [`List<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx), documented at [List(T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Public static (**Shared** in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List<T>, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. For an inherently thread–safe alternative, see the [ImmutableList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

So no, in your specific example, it is not thread-safe, but it can be made thread-safe by using a different collection type.